# Is there an option to create a Snapchat-like features addon to interact with video calls?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a way to create an add-on “snapchat-like” video feature for the video calls?

I want to build an app that will get and manipulate the user camera stream source, then the user will decide if and when to share it on his ms-teams calls.

Answer (score 1):

Currently we only have [Calls and online meetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) support for bot. There is no support for processing video call stream yet.

As of now we don't have more details to share on this.